# R - how to filter data with a list of arguments to produce multiple data frames and graphs

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, filter, assign

I am looking for a way to use a list of filter arguments to produce different objects. I have a data set for which I want to make several graphs. However, I want all these graphs based on subsets of the dataset. For illustrative purposes I have made the following data.

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("b1", "b2", "b1", "b2"),
                 yield = c("15", "10", "5", "0"),
                 temperature = c("2", "21", "26", "13"),
                 Season = c("Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn"),
                 profit = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Also, I have a list of filter arguments.

```
filters <- c("brand=='b1'",
             "profit",
             "Season=='Summer'",
             "profit==FALSE",
             "yield >= 10",
             "")
```

What I would want is that I could use a for loop to have all these filters produce objects with the filtered data, and subsequently plot graphs. I have tried this in the following way.

```
for(i in 1:length(filters)){
  assign(paste0("df", i), filter(df, factor(filters[i])))
  assign(paste0("plot", i), ggplot(database, aes(x = temperature, y = yield)) + geom_point())
}
```

However, this did not work because the `filter()` function does not accept `<fct>` as an argument, nor `<chr>` (e.g., `"brand=='b1'"`). What I would want is `brand=='b1'`, so `filter()` accepts it as an argument. Does anybody have an idea to do this?

Also, as an additional question, I would like to automate the whole process and end with an combined graph, so `grid.arrange()` at the end. Of course I could automate the `ncol` and `nrow` with some devision of `length(filters)`. But how to I get all the produced plots in the `grid.arrange()`? This should probably be outside the for loop, right? Any ideas here?

Comment: `filter` expects a *condition*, which must always be `logical`. It is not clear what you mean by `factor(...)` in that sense. In general, I strongly discourage use of `assign` in this way, typically something `list`-like is much better (and R-idiomatic). Perhaps read http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207

Comment: The way I wrote the script, the elements of the list were given to the `filter` as type factor. That is what I was trying to explain. I can bypass this with `eval` and `parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `eval` and `parse`.

Also, a `lapply` over a custom function sounds more reasonable than a `for` loop with `assign`. The result is a list of `ggplot` objects.

To set all charts all together `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package works fine. You just need to assign the list of your charts to the argument called `grobs`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(type = c("b1", "b2", "b1", "b2"),
                 yield = c(15, 10, 5, 0),
                 temperature = c("2", "21", "26", "13"),
                 Season = c("Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn"),
                 profit = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

filters <- list("type=='b1'",
                "profit",
                "Season=='Summer'",
                "profit==FALSE",
                "yield >= 10",
                "TRUE")


myfun <- function(fltr, df){

  df <- filter(df, eval(parse(text = fltr)))
  ggplot(df, aes(x = temperature, y = yield)) + geom_point()

}


ggs <- lapply(filters, myfun, df = df)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = ggs)
```

[image]

I made a couple of changes in your data: yield must be a numeric since you are using a filter applicable only to numeric vectors and the last filter (which was empty) is now equal to "TRUE" [I supposed you wanted to take everything in consideration]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me. And yes, there were some typos from my side: yield had to be numeric and with `filter()` I meant `filter(TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than storing your filters, as character strings, it would be better to store them a quosures. For example

```
library(rlang)
filters <- quos(type=='b1',
             profit,
             Season=='Summer',
             profit==FALSE,
             yield >= 10,
             TRUE)
```

Then you can fairly easily map over these with `purrr::map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
map(filters, ~df %>% filter(!!!.x) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = temperature, y = yield)) + geom_point())
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the difference here between using `!!` and `!!!`?  I see the same set of plots using either, so I'm wondering in what case the two operators would give different results.

Comment: I guess in this case they would be the same. In general, `!!!` can expand to more than one argument while `!!` would expand to only one.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the input data in the Note at the end which fixes up some inconsistencies in the data shown in the question, makes temperature and yield numeric and improves `profit == FALSE` to just `!profit`.  Define a function `Plot` which takes a filter, subsets `df` and plots it.  Then apply it to each `filter` and use `grid.arrange`.  This uses ggplot2 and gridExtra but no additional packages and does not use `eval` explicitly.

(An alternative to the `grid.arrange` line would be `cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist=plots)` which gives a slightly different layout.)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

Plot <- function(x) {
  data <- do.call("subset", list(df, parse(text = x)))
  ggplot(data, aes(temperature, yield)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + ggtitle(x)
}

plots <- Map(Plot, filters)
do.call("grid.arrange", plots)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
df <- data.frame(brand = c("b1", "b2", "b1", "b2"),
                 yield = c(15, 10, 5, 0),
                 temperature = c(2, 21, 26, 13),
                 Season = c("Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn"),
                 profit = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

filters <- c("brand=='b1'",
             "profit",
             "Season=='Summer'",
             "!profit",
             "yield >= 10",
             TRUE)
```