# R - Defining a function which recognises arguments not as objects, but as being part of the call

Tags: r, plot, user-defined-functions, indirection, standard-evaluation

I'm trying to define a function which returns a graphical object in R. The idea is that I can then call this function with different arguments multiple times using an `for` loop or `lapply` function, then plotting the list of `grobs` in `gridExtra::grid.arrange`. However, I did not get that far yet. I'm having trouble with r recognising the arguments as being part of the call. I've made some code to show you my problem. I have tried quoting and unquoting the arguments, using `unqoute()` in the function (["Object not found" error within a user defined function, eval() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617354/object-not-found-error-within-a-user-defined-function-eval-function)), using `eval(parse())` ([R - how to filter data with a list of arguments to produce multiple data frames and graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273929/r-how-to-filter-data-with-a-list-of-arguments-to-produce-multiple-data-frames)), using `!!`, etc. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone know how I should handle this?

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)

data_km <- data.frame(Duration1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                      Event1 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1),
                      Duration2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
                      Event2 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1),
                      Duration3 = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
                      Event3 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1),
                      Area = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))

# this is working perfectly
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(Duration1, Event1) ~ Area, data = data_km))
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(Duration2, Event2) ~ Area, data = data_km))
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(Duration3, Event3) ~ Area, data = data_km))

myfun <- function(TimeVar, EventVar){
  ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(eval(parse(text = TimeVar), eval(parse(text = EventVar)) ~ Area, data = data_km))
}

x <- myfun("Duration1", "Event1")
plot(x)
```

Comment: The question isn't really specific to survival analysis but would rather apply to any fitting function that involved R-formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to study some tutorials about computing on the language. I like doing it with base R, e.g., using `bquote`.

```
myfun <- function(TimeVar, EventVar){
  TimeVar <- as.name(TimeVar)
  EventVar <- as.name(EventVar) 

  fit <- eval(bquote(survfit(Surv(.(TimeVar), .(EventVar)) ~ Area, data = data_km)))
  ggsurvplot(fit)
}

x <- myfun("Duration1", "Event1")
print(x)
#works
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. However, in my function, I also want to use the maximum value of the TimeVar. I'm trying this ```MaxTimeVar <- eval(bquote(max(data_km$.(TimeVar))))``` but it gives an error. Does it work differently when using the ```$``` sign?

Comment: `$` does non-standard evaluation and that interferes with `bquote`. `$` is intended for interactive use only. You could use `bquote(max(data_km[[.(TimeVar)]]))`, but if you use the original character value (before using `as.name`), you could simply do `max(data_km[[Timevar]])`, which would be better.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. Will study some tutorials about this, still a lot to learn.