# object '...' not found in R Functions with lm -->> (Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '...' not found)

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data-analysis, lm

I'm using the moderndrive package to calculate a linear regression but using a function. I am trying to create a function where i can just pass in two selected columns(e.g deaths & cases, titles of the columns) from my data frame (Rona_2020). Below is the function...

```
score_model_Fxn <- function(y, x){
  score_mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = Rona_2020)
  Reg_Table <- get_regression_table(score_mod)
print(paste('The regression table is', Reg_Table))
}
```

when I run the function ...

```
score_model_Fxn(deaths, cases)
```

I get ...

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'deaths' not found
```

What should i do? I have looked several similar issues but to no avail.

Comment: you are using quasiquotation outside of the scope

Comment: `score_model_Fxn("deaths", "cases")` and in your function: `lm(paste0(y, "~", x), data=Rona_2020)`

Comment: @jogo https://stackoverflow.com/a/60604226/1412059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the coolest ways of doing this is using the new recipes package to generate the formula for us and then manipulating a tibble to produce or result

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stringr':
#> 
#>     fixed
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
library(moderndive)

score_model_Fxn <- function(df,x, y){
  formula_1 <- df %>% 
    recipe() %>%
    update_role({{x}},new_role = "outcome") %>% 
    update_role({{y}},new_role = "predictor") %>% 
    formula()

  Reg_Table <- mtcars %>%
    summarise(score_mod = list(lm(formula_1,data = .))) %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Reg_Table = list(get_regression_table(score_mod))) %>% 
    pull(Reg_Table)

  print(paste('The regression table is', Reg_Table))
  Reg_Table
}

k <- mtcars %>%
  score_model_Fxn(x = cyl,y = gear)
#> [1] "The regression table is list(term = c(\"intercept\", \"gear\"), estimate = c(10.585, -1.193), std_error = c(1.445, 0.385), statistic = c(7.324, -3.101), p_value = c(0, 0.004), lower_ci = c(7.633, -1.978), upper_ci = c(13.537, -0.407))"

k
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   term      estimate std_error statistic p_value lower_ci upper_ci
#>   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 intercept    10.6      1.44       7.32   0         7.63   13.5  
#> 2 gear         -1.19     0.385     -3.10   0.004    -1.98   -0.407
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! One question, In the creation of Reg_table... Do u mean df instead of mtcars in the function?

Comment: I don't have df installed on my computer that is why I  asked for a reprex, replace mtcars for you requirement

Comment: Your function was ok. But I did some changes... I changed the outcome to y and predictor to x. As for the mtcars position, i just replaced it with df. These changes gave me the correct answer without using a function, including a similar answer  to Roland's. As for the print paste, I realised it was just redundant. Just allowed print(Reg_table). Thanks for your feedback and effort.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do by passing `deaths` and `cases` is called non-standard evaluation. You need to combine this with computing on the language if you want to run a model with the correct formula and scoping. Computing on the language can be done with `substitute` and `bquote`.

```
library(moderndive)
score_model_Fxn <- function(y, x, data){

  #get the symbols passed as arguments:
  data <- substitute(data)
  y <- substitute(y)
  x <- substitute(x)

  #substitute them into the lm call and evaluate the call:
  score_mod <- eval(bquote(lm(.(y) ~ .(x), data = .(data))))

  Reg_Table <- get_regression_table(score_mod)

  message('The regression table is') #better than your paste solution
  print(Reg_Table)

  invisible(score_mod) #a function should always return something useful
}

mod <- score_model_Fxn(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, iris)
#The regression table is
## A tibble: 2 x 7
#  term        estimate std_error statistic p_value lower_ci upper_ci
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 intercept      6.53      0.479     13.6    0         5.58    7.47 
#2 Sepal.Width   -0.223     0.155     -1.44   0.152    -0.53    0.083

print(mod)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#     6.5262      -0.2234
```

You could have the function return `Reg_Table` instead if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I did not know about the message section. So I have learned new things in addition!

Answer (score 0):

For those that might be interested...I modified Bruno's answer.

```
library(tidyverse); library(recipes); library(moderndive)

score_model_Fxn2 <- function(df,x, y){
  formula_1 <- df %>% 
    recipe() %>%
    update_role({{y}},new_role = "outcome") %>% 
    update_role({{x}},new_role = "predictor") %>% 
    formula()
  Reg_Table <- df %>%
    summarise(score_mod = list(lm(formula_1,data = .))) %>%
    rowwise() %>%  
     mutate(Reg_Table = list(get_regression_table(score_mod))) %>% 
    pull(Reg_Table)
  print(Reg_Table)
}
score_model_Fxn2()
```

Comment: I mean you didn't even change the parameters, this is literally my answer without a reprex...

Comment: Yes... That's why you were acknowledged. :)

Comment: Ok, I am going to guess you haven't seem too many SO questions because of your points, which is fine btw I even forgot to to welcome you to SO, basically we don't necessarily answer your question precisely to your data, even more so when you don't provide said data, so my answer is basically your answer but you are not acknowledging  it by the point system implemented in SO, which gives me an incentive to answer questions, tldr I am less prone to answer the next question that you or another beginners asks

Comment: You are right. I'm new to SO. Forgive  me if I have done something wrong.